# Other conditions than necessary and sufficient conditions, $\Rightarrow$, $\Leftrightarrow$?

Tags: logic, soft-question, education

I know that $$A\Rightarrow B$$ means that $A$ is a necessary condition for $B$ and $B$ is a sufficient condition for $A$.

Also, $$A\Leftrightarrow B$$ means that $A$ is necessary and sufficient condition for $B$ and vice versa.

Is there any other relation that are neither necessary nor sufficient conditions? (Maybe my question depends on the context? or it is very board?)

Comment: It's the other way around for $\Rightarrow$; B is necessary for A, and A sufficient for B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, if $A\implies B$, then $A$ is a sufficient condition for $B$ and $B$ is a necessary condition for $A$. It makes sense that way since $A\implies B$ means that if you have $A$, then you get $B$ for free, meaning that having $A$ is enough (is sufficient) for having $B$. On the other hand, if $A\implies B$, then if you do not have $B$, you also do not have $A$ since $\neg B\implies \neg A$. This means that if you want $A$, you at least need $B$, making $B$ a necessary condition.

As for other conditions, well, if they are neither necesary nor sufficient, you can hardly call them conditions, don't you think?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much.